# what is the [count=\i] in \foreach for?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Can someone explain what does `[count=\i]` in a `foreach` mean?

Antal S-Z's answer to [Fitting a list of points with TikZ and its \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/fitting-a-list-of-points-with-tikz-and-its-foreach) use this. It is also mentioned in [Increment loop variable in inner foreach loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19122/increment-loop-variable-in-inner-foreach-loop), but I am not able to locate documentation on this in the TikZ-PGF manual (V2.10)

Comment: The TikZ manual has a nice index, which is quite useful for finding where an option is described.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Section *Options to customize the foreach-statement.* (pages 507-508):

> `/pgf/foreach/count=
>   <macro>from<value>` (no default) This
>   key allows `<macro>` to hold the
>   position in the list of the current
>   item. The optional `from<value>`
>   statement allows the counting to begin
>   from `<value>`.

So, for example, in

```
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,e}
```

the `\x` will take the values `a,b,c,d,e`, while `\xi` will take the values `1,2,3,4,5`, and in

```
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 3] in {a,...,e}
```

the `\x` will still take the values  `a,b,c,d,e`, while `\xi` will now take the values `3,4,5,6,7`.

Comment: Since which version of Tikz is this function available?

Comment: (for Python people) it resembles Python's builtin "enumerate" function