# Using double for-loop in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, animations

In the manual one can find the `...` option to obtain a range in the for-loop. For example:

```
\foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,6} {\x, }
```

On the other hand, one can have a for-loop which runs over two variables simultaneously. For example:

```
\foreach \i / \y in {1/0,2/0.25,3/0.5,4/0.75,5/1} {
     \only<\i>{
     \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
     \draw (0,0) -- (1,\y);
     }
}
```

which can produce some simple "animation" when used along with beamer. My question is how to combine the two. Namely, I would like to have something like:

```
\foreach \i / \y in {1/0,2/0.25,...,5/1}
```

which will produce the list *(1,0),(2,0.25),(3,0.5),(4,0.75),(5,1)*. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I think it's no (see the pgfmanual). It's only possible with for example : `\foreach \x in {0\pi,0.5\pi,...\pi,3\pi} {$\x$, }`  the ... statement have exactly the same pattern, except that, instead of dots, they have a number or a character. So you need to avoid ... in your case but perhaps I'm wrong and a great expert can find a solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. However, in your case the `/` notations isn't really necessary:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y [count=\i] in {0,0.25,...,1} {
     \only<\i>{
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
     \draw (0,0) -- (1,\y);
     }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For more complicated cases, when one variable is dependent on the other via some formula, you can also use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \y using (\i-1)*0.25] in {1,2,...,5} {
     \only<\i>{
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
     \draw (0,0) -- (1,\y);
     }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Your first snippet solved my problem! Can you give a reference to these two solutions? So I can understand them better? Thnx anyway!

Comment: @Dror: pages 507 and 508 of the TikZ v2.10 manual (“Options to customize the foreach-statement”).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21557/what-is-the-count-i-in-foreach-for

Comment: Thnx!! I stopped on page 505...