# Commas in edge labels during for-loop in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making a picture of an automaton where the transitions have comma-separated tuples for weights. This isn't a problem until I try to space out transitions in the same part of the graph using the for-loop syntax (hat-tip to: [How to draw a many edges loop above - tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60720/how-to-draw-a-many-edges-loop-above-tikz)). Because the edge labels for the for-loop are separated by commas, each element in the tuple is grabbed as part of a new label by the loop, rather than being part of the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                semithick]

\node[initial,state, accepting, align = center] (A) {0};

\path (A)    edge [loop above, align=center] node {a:a \\ $\langle 0, 0, 0, 0 \rangle$} (A);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\foreach \looseness/\label [count=\n] in {15/i:a \\ $\langle 2 1 1 1\rangle$ }
    \path [->] (A) edge [
        loop above, align = center,
        every loop/.append style={
        looseness=\looseness,
        in=60-0.8*\looseness,
        out=120+0.8*\looseness
    }] node {\label} ();
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To avoid this I have omitted commas. The result is that the manually specified arc looks the way I want it to, but the one created by the for loop does not (no commas between elements). I get the impression from [Using double for-loop in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21569/using-double-for-loop-in-tikz) that the for-loop just does not support what I am trying to do, but I'd like to make sure.

P.S. The graph I am making does use several arcs, so there is some reason to use a for-loop.

[image: single state automaton with comma separated and non-comma separated weight vectors]

Comment: Can you not just use `{$\langle 2, 1, 1, 1\rangle$}` in specifying the label? The curly brackets will protect the commas. This is the standard way to include commas in `\foreach` loops with TikZ as far as I know.

Comment: Hey, it works! Thank you. If you write it as an answer, I'll mark it as the preferred one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to use values which include commas in `\foreach` loops in TikZ is to protect them using curly brackets. (Note that coordinates can be handled specially so don't use this method for those.)

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=50pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
    semithick]

    \node[initial,state, accepting, align = center] (A) {0};

    \path (A)    edge [loop above, align=center] node {a:a \\ $\langle 0, 0, 0, 0 \rangle$} (A);
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \foreach \looseness/\label [count=\n] in {12/i:a \\ {$\langle 2, 1, 1, 1\rangle$} }
      \path [->] (A) edge [
      loop above, align = center,
      every loop/.append style={
        looseness=\looseness,
        in=60-.8*\looseness,
        out=120+.8*\looseness
      }] node {\label} ();
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: commas in loops]